# calling Webservice from Excel 2007?

Tags: web-services, excel, excel-2007, vba

**Problem:**
I would like to extract some data from a webservice and put it into Excel.

**For example**: A webservice method "GetPerformance" with Parameters X,Y,Z will return a table containing funds and their performance. I would like to extract specific rows and dump the data into a sheet.

How can I achieve such a feat with VBA or other plugins?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See if this link help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798260/html-parsing-of-cricinfo-scorecards/8846791#8846791

Comment: Perhaps, I'll try it out. Will it take parameters?

Comment: Can you gimme an example of what you want?

Comment: What about WSDL? Is this what you are after?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at my answer here : [Excel doc contents to webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270839/excel-doc-contents-to-webservice/11298452#11298452)

Specifically, check out the method called "SaveNewStaff" in my answer (which is just a rewrite of what the author of the original question had already done); It's a good example on how you would call a web service with POST.

If you need a more specific answer, please provide some details about the method being called, and the parameters and return data of the web method.

Cheers!
:)