# Where to find VBA functions for working with internet explorer

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am working on a VBA function to go to a webpage, find a single HTML element, and display its contents. Here is what I have so far.

```
Function WebTableToSheet(webpage As String, tag As String, count As Integer) As String


  'Tested using IE7,  Excel 2000 SP1, and Windows XP
  Dim objIE As Object
  Dim varTables, varTable, document
  Dim allTags, tags
  Dim varRows, varRow
  Dim varCells, varCell
  Dim lngRow As Long, lngColumn As Long
  Dim strBuffer As String

  Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

 'Setup
  With objIE
    .AddressBar = False
    .StatusBar = False
    .MenuBar = False
    .Toolbar = 0
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate webpage
  End With

  'Load webpage
  While objIE.Busy
  Wend
  While objIE.document.ReadyState <> "complete"
  Wend


  varTable = objIE.document.All

  allTags = objIE.document.All.tags(tag)

  WebTableToSheet = allTags.Item(count)

  Debug.Print "Testing function"




Cleanup:
    Set varCell = Nothing: Set varCells = Nothing
    Set varRow = Nothing: Set varRows = Nothing
    Set varTable = Nothing: Set varTables = Nothing
    objIE.Quit
    Set objIE = Nothing
End Function
```

I am able to open InternetExplorer, got to the webpage specified in the function, but when I try searching for a specific tag, it seems to fail. I have had trouble searching for Microsoft VBA Internet Explorer documentation and knew what variables and methods are available for this task?

Comment: You can use `getElementsByTagName` and `getElementById` here (depending on whether you're searching by element id or type).  Since you're getting a collection or object back from these methods you should also use `Set allTags = ...`

Comment: If you want to get into data scraping then this is worth a read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798260/html-parsing-of-cricinfo-scorecards

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend setting a reference to shdocvw.dll and the Microsoft HTML Object Library. In XP shdocvw.dll is in your system32 folder, the HTML Object Library should be in your list of references. I only have access to XP at the moment, so you'll have to do a search for any other ver of windows you're using. Then in your code you can do the following:

```
Dim IE as SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim doc as HTMLDocument
Dim el as IHTMLElement
Set IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

With IE
  .navigate "some.webpage.com"
  .visible = true
End With

Do
  'Nothing
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE ' = 4

Set doc = IE.Document
Set el = doc.getElementById("someElementId")
If Not el Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox el.innerText
End If
```

Comment: Of course, it isn't *necessary* to set the library references, but it'll certainly make it easier to traverse HTML DOM, especially if you're not familiar with it.

Answer (score 2):

Team,
IE webpage full loading check use below mentioned code

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))

Do Until IE.Busy = False
   DoEvents
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ieApp.Navigate "Https://duckduckgo.com/"

'Wait for Internet Explorer to finish loading
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do While ieApp.Busy And Not ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

ieApp.Document.getelementbyid("search_form_input_homepage").Value = "Gajendra Santosh"
ieApp.Document.getelementbyid("search_button_homepage").Click
```