# VBA automation to copy/paste from websites

Tags: internet-explorer, excel, vba

OK.  So here's my thought process of how this code should work.  I have a sheet that has a list of web addresses that I would like to use the for loop to iterate through.  For each web address I'd like to copy and paste the whole web page to a temporary sheet in the workbook.  After the page is pasted into Excel(2010) I would do some formatting.  Only copy and paste what I want from the temporary sheet to a master sheet.  The next link is then navigated in Internet Explorer, and like before the web page is pasted to the temp sheet and then what I need is appended to the master sheet.  I'm experiencing the following issues:

1) No matter what worksheet I declare for the web page to paste to it always pastes to the first sheet.  This happens to be the sheet that I have my command button on, but that shouldn't make a difference.  Should it?

2) The appending to the master sheet is not working.  When the macro is finished running the only records that appear to have been pasted to the master sheet is from the last web page.

I'm thinking that maybe what I need to do is add a pause of a certain amount of time between selecting/copying/pasting the web page to Excel to fix issue #2.  Help with either of these issues would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim IE As Object

startTime = Now()

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

For rows1 = 2 To 11
    For columns1 = 2 To 2
        strLink = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("links").Cells(rows1, columns1)

With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate strLink
Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
Loop

IE.ExecWB 17, 0
IE.ExecWB 12, 2

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("temp").Paste Range("A1")

End With

'Copy/paste and format from temp to master sheet
nextRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("master").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("temp").Range("A173:S247").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range("A" & nextRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Next columns1
Next rows1

endTime = Now()

MsgBox ("Done running.  It took from " & startTime & " to " & endTime & ".")


End Sub
```

Comment: Why follow such a lengthy process? Why not extract just the relevant info rather than the whole page? You might find this link interesting... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798260/html-parsing-of-cricinfo-scorecards

Comment: how would you do the same thing with chrome? i can get it to open an instance of chrome, but as soon as it gets to trying to make it visible it errors out.

`Dim CHR As Object

  Shell ("""C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe""")

For rows1 = 1 To 5000
    For columns1 = 1 To 1
    
With CHR
    .Visible = True`

one it gets to .visible it errors out.

Answer (score 1):

Issue 1: your code `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("temp").Paste Range("A1")` will always refer to the active sheet -- Range("A1") is implied to be using the active sheet since there is no defined sheet object.  You need to reference the correct sheet in the argument of the function.  So try `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("temp").Paste ThisWorkbook.Sheets("othersheet").Range("A1")` if you want the screen scrape pasted to something other than "temp"

(your code will be much more readable if you set ThisWorkbook and each Sheet to a variable)

Issue 2: You are looking to paste after the last row on the Master sheet. Lose the first line of that section, keep the second, the replace the third with

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 2, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

(again, you should use variables to represent workbook and worksheet objects to make your code cleaner)