# Collecting data from webpage with VBA

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba

I would like to get some informations into an excel sheet from this webpage: http://www.livescore.in/

My code look like this:

```
Dim page1 As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim myDiv As Object
Set page1 = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

page1.Open "GET", "http://www.livescore.in", False
page1.send

Do Until page1.readyState = 4 And page1.Status = 200
    DoEvents
Loop
html.body.innerHTML = page1.responseText
Set myDiv = html.getElementById("fscon")
Debug.Print myDiv.innerText
```

I would like to work in the "fs" div which is in the "fscon" div
The result of this script is "Loading ..."

I know what is the problem: When the base page is loading some javascript will fill up the "fscon" div. My script is only sees the base page (without the data mathces)

My question is how can I wait until the full page is loading?

Thanks

Update:
This code is working. It uses IE object, i will test how fast is scanning all the matches from the page.

```
Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
Dim ieDoc As Object
Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer
ieApp.Visible = False
ieApp.navigate "http://www.livescore.in"

Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Set ieDoc = ieApp.document
Debug.Print ieDoc.all.Item("fscon").innerText

Set ieDoc = Nothing
ieApp.Quit
Set ieApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged java?

Comment: @BackSlash because it would be **much** easier in Java. Ha.

Comment: See if [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798260/html-parsing-of-cricinfo-scorecards) helps you?

Comment: one way is : use selenium and load the page in a browser and then harvest it, maybe a headless version of  firefox

Comment: Sorry, it is Javascript of course