# Http Response decode

Tags: php, asp.net, http, httpresponse, decoding

This question is in regards to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211477/collecting-data-from-webpage-with-vba). I am trying to find out how the data in below image coming. Using firebug watching the http request i believe (not sure) data comes from http://d.livescore.in/x/feed/f_1_0_2_en_4 but i am not able to understand the response.

What kind of response is it ? (json/xml or what?). 
Is that encoded ? 
Is there a way to decode it?

URL for site : http://www.livescore.in/

[image]

Comment: Have you found out the way to extract data from the response?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the server is not configured properly and does not return Content-Type filed.
This is what I have received (checked by [HTTP Debugger Pro](http://www.httpdebugger.com)):

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Varnish
Content-Length: 323
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Tue, 08 Oct 2013 07:58:49 GMT
Age: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

The response contains nothing interesting, but a flat html with "401 Unauthorized" body.

If you need more info, then send me credentials, I will check and send you more info.

Thanks,
Khachatur