# how to download data using vba excel 2011

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, html-table, excel-2011

I've seen this answer:  [html parsing of cricinfo scorecards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798260/html-parsing-of-cricinfo-scorecards/8846791#8846791)

these variable types, however, are not available in excel 2011:

```
Dim tbl As HTMLTable
Dim tr As HTMLTableRow
```

Is there another way to get data from the web using excel 2011?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library. In your VBA editor window click Tools > Reference and select the Microsoft HTML Object Library. That should make those variable types available.

If you can't find it click browse and find: C:\WINDOWS\system32\mshtml.tlb This comes with MS Internet Explorer; if you don't have it, download and install MS Internet Explorer.

Oh... You have Excel 2011 (for Mac); I guess the Windows file path won't work for you. I'm guessing that if you install MS Internet Explorer you would also get the MS HTML Object library.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see that library listed under references.  How to I add it?

Comment: Don't know. You can try it.

Comment: From what I can see, IE is not available for mac.

Comment: I googled internet explorer for mac and found an old version; don't know if you want that or not. Otherwise I guess you're back to "Is there another way to get data from the web using excel 2011?" I can't help you with that.

Comment: I appreciate your effort!  Thanks.