# Excel 2010 VBA - Pull Table from website

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to Excel VBA and I was given some code to play with.  I successfully modified it once, but then I tried to modify it again and it won't pull the right info.  It might be because I don't know the table id for sure?  I don't understand all of the code from this example...that's probably the other issue.  Anyways I'm trying to pull the Historical Prices Table from [this page](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=TWTR&a=04&b=30&c=2012&d=01&e=7&f=2014&g=d).  It pulls some data, but not the correct data.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Here is my current code:

```
Sub GrabHistData()

    Dim Ptrtbl As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim htm As Object
    Dim elemCollection As Object

    Set htm = CreateObject("htmlFile")

    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=TWTR&a=04&b=30&c=2012&d=01&e=7&f=2014&g=d", False
        .send
        htm.body.innerhtml = .responsetext
    End With

    Set elemCollection = htm.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")

    Ptrtbl = 1
    For Each elem In elemCollection
        Ptrtbl = Ptrtbl + 1
        If elem.ID <> "yfncsumtab" Then GoTo Nxtelem
        With elemCollection(Ptrtbl)

                For c = 0 To (.Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
                    Cells(r + 1, c + 1) = .Rows(r).Cells(c).innertext
                Next c

        End With
        Exit For
Nxtelem:
    Next elem

End Sub
```

Comment: Would [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798260/html-parsing-of-cricinfo-scorecards) help?

Comment: There's a "download to CSV" link on that page, sao you could instead just open the file directly in excel using `http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=TWTR&a=04&b=30&c=2012&d=01&e=7&f=2014&g=d&ignore=.csv` as the path (which is more or less the same pattern as the URL you're trying to scrape from...)

Comment: Ahh, good ideas.  I really like the firefox element searching options.  I also see now that the csv file method could be much easier.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with your current approach, this works for me...

```
Sub GrabHistData()
    Dim Ptrtbl As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim htm As Object
    Dim elemCollection As Object

    Set htm = CreateObject("htmlFile")

    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=TWTR&a=04&b=30&c=2012&d=01&e=7&f=2014&g=d", False
        .send
        htm.body.innerhtml = .responseText
    End With

    Set elemCollection = htm.getElementsByTagName("td")
    For Each itm In elemCollection
        If itm.classname = "yfnc_tabledata1" Then
            ActiveCell = itm.innertext

            If ActiveCell.Column = 7 Then
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, -6).Select
            Else
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```