# .ReadyState & .Busy Is Not Waiting For IE Page To Load

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer-11

I have some VBA to launch a company intranet site which will bring me directly to the document I am searching for. I need to wait for the page to finish loading, and then hit the "Print" button which will open the document in a Adobe Reader supported IE tab, and from there I save it as a PDF to a drive.

My issue is that the loop I have to wait until the webpage is loaded does not properly wait. Doing some research on SO, I've seen this is a known issue with newer versions of IE. I have since tried playing with some `XMLHTTP` methods, but I am unfamiliar with those, and my attempts with it have also fallen short (not sure how I would navigate to the next page by hitting the Print link using `XMLHTTP`).

My current VBA is as follows, and `ieApp` is `New InternetExplorerMedium`.

```
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    IE_Count = 0
    IE_Count = objShell.Windows.Count
    For x = 0 To (IE_Count - 1)
        On Error Resume Next
        my_url = ""
        my_title = ""
        my_url = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Location
        my_title = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Title

        If my_url Like "http://ctdayppv002/Home/DocViewer?" & "*" Then
            Set ie = objShell.Windows(x)
            Do While ieApp.ReadyState <> 4 And ie.Busy
                DoEvents
            Loop
            For Each ee In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
                If ee.ID = "printDocLink" Then
                 ee.Click: DoEvents: Sleep 1500
                    Do While ie.ReadyState <> 4 And ie.Busy
                        DoEvents
                    Loop
                 Exit For
                End If
            Next ee
            Exit For
        Else
        End If
    Next
```

If I add a bunch of `Sleep` time, then it will wait, until a document comes up that exceeds the time I told it to `Sleep`, so obviously that isn't a reliable solution.

Using the following questions for reference, I have tried to use `XMLHTTP`, but also noticed comments that this method may not work with JavaScript sites.

[VBA hanging on ie.busy and readystate check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480369/vba-hanging-on-ie-busy-and-readystate-check)

[web scraping with vba using XMLHTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639724/web-scraping-with-vba-using-xmlhttp)

One of my attempts with `XMLHTTP`:

```
Public ieApp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Set ieApp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    With ieApp

        .Open "GET", urlString, False
        .send

        While ieApp.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend

        Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        Dim HTMLBody As MSHTML.HTMLBody

        Set HTMLDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        Set HTMLBody = HTMLDoc.body
        HTMLBody.innerHTML = ieApp.responseText
        Debug.Print HTMLBody.innerHTML

    End With
```

Within the resulting `HTMLBody.innerHTML` I do not see the `"printDocLink"` element.

FYI - I have been emailing a rep from the company that created the website database, and they do not believe there is an API call that can directly export as a PDF, which I was hoping would be available to skip over the "Print" button entirely.

Comment: What exactly do you see when it fails?  Instead of having a single Sleep, you could use a shorter one in a loop which checks (with error handling if necessary) for the required result.

Comment: @TimWilliams are you referring to the Internet Explorer approach, or the XMLHTTP? 

When using IE, I don't necessarily "see" anything, it just moves on to the next part of the code, which obviously doesn't work because it didn't get a chance to hit the Print button. Of course, adding a long Sleep gives it time to load and hit print, which then the rest of the VBA code works fine.

Using XMLHTTP it seems to do the same thing, but I told it to print the innerHTML which returned the entire JavaScript for the page.

Comment: @TimWilliams forgive me for sounding stupid, but arent I checking for the desired result when I use the `If ee.ID = "printDocLink" Then`? And the attempt at not advancing until that element exists would be above at the `Do While` loop?

Comment: @TimWilliams okay I think I figured out what you were saying. I did this: `Do Until .Document.getElementById("printDocLink") <> 0 DoEvents: Sleep 1000 Loop` and it seems to be working. I'll have to try it out with some larger documents that take longer to load.

Comment: An example https://stackoverflow.com/a/55494738/6241235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the advice from Tim Williams and QHarr, I found a solution that works for me.

I added a `Do Until`, and also a timer for 6 seconds:

```
            t = Now + TimeValue("0:00:6")
            Do Until .Document.getElementById("printDocLink") <> 0
                DoEvents: Sleep 1000
                If Now > t Then
                    Call Not_Found_PPV(N, searchitem)
                    .Quit
                    Set ieApp = Nothing
                    GoTo NxtInv
                End If
            Loop
```