# last column is not displaying from the table

Tags: vba, excel

I have to derive the price table from http://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/OffersOfProduct/143513.html

So far I have done this code

```
Sub test()       

  Set sht = Sheets("Tabelle4")
  rCount = 1

    Dim objIE As Object, objTbl As Object, objTR As Object
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

    With objIE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "http://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/OffersOfProduct/143513.html"

        Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set objTbl = objIE.Document.getElementById("offers-list")
        Set objTR = objTbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")


        rCount = 1
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each td In objTR
            Cells(rCount, 1) = td.all(0).outerText
            Cells(rCount, 2) = td.all(4).innerText

            'Cells(rCount, 3) = td.all(2).outerText
            'Cells(rCount, 4) = td.all(3).outerText

            'Cells(rCount, 6) = td.all(5).innerText
            'Cells(rCount, 7) = td.all(6).innerText
            rCount = rCount + 1
        Next
        On Error GoTo 0

    End With

    objIE.Quit
    Set objIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

It gives me first two column but the last column that contains the shop name is not displaying. Can any one help which one is the td() of the last column

Comment: Why are you using VBA for this? A simple Data|From Web will get you everything that you want? You may want to see [2) Using Excel's inbuilt facility to get data from the web](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798260/html-parsing-of-cricinfo-scorecards/8846791#8846791) I just tried it and it works.

Comment: @SiddharthRout i need to develop a price comparison tool that's why am using vba

Comment: in that case in the above link, there is vba code for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to figure what type of data each td object has you have to add them to the watch. For example:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, in the *td* object I am watching i can tell that the value of

```
td.all.item(0).innertext
```

is:
Canon Nah­linse 500D 72 mm

Now you should go through the other values in the watch window until you can find the index of the shop in the *td* object

Comment: This is the code based on the same code that I mentioned in the link below the question ;)

Comment: thanks for the code but what if i want to derive a particular table only....I have used .WebTables = "offers-list" but it gives me error