# Web scraping - create object for IE

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

```
Sub Get_Data()


Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "http://www.scramble.nl/military-database/usaf"
Do While ie.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
SendKeys "03-3114"
SendKeys "{ENTER}"


End Sub
```

The code below searches for keyboard typed value **03-3114** and gets a data in the table. If I 'd like to search for value which is already in cell A1 and scrape values from table for "Code, Type, CN, Unit" in cell range ("B1:E1") what should I do?

Comment: HI... can you explain from which table u refering..

Comment: @HA560   I mean tr.rowBoard table I have a problem with trying to import any value from that table into excel cell...

Answer (score 0):

You are using `SendKeys` which are highly unreliable :) Why not find the name of the textbox and the search button and directly interact with it as shown below?

```
Sub Get_Data()
    Dim ie As Object, objInputs As Object

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate "http://www.scramble.nl/military-database/usaf"

    Do While ie.readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    '~~> Get the ID of the textbox where you want to output
    ie.Document.getElementById("serial").Value = "03-3114"

    '~~> Here we try to identify the search button and click it
    Set objInputs = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each ele In objInputs
        If ele.Name Like "sbm" Then
            ele.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Note**: To understand how I got the names `serial` and `sbm`, refer to the explanation given just above the image below.

> The code below searches for keyboard typed value 03-3114 and gets a data in the table. If I 'd like to search for value which is already in cell A1 and scrape values from table for "Code, Type, CN, Unit" in cell range ("B1:E1") what should I do?

Directly put the value from `A1` in lieu of the hardcoded value

```
ie.Document.getElementById("serial").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```

To get the values from the table, identify the elements of the table by right clicking on it in the browser and clicking on "Inspect/Inspect Element(*In Chrome it is just `Inspect`*)" as shown below.

[image]

I can give you the code but I want you to do it yourself. If you are still stuck then update the question with the code that you tried and then we will take it from there.

**Interesting read**: [html parsing of cricinfo scorecards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798260/html-parsing-of-cricinfo-scorecards)

Comment: Great hint! @ Siddharth Rout , I am having a hard time to import Code value from the web table (tr.rowBoard) into B1 cell in excel, I think Xpath is a problem but the xpath    //*[@id="wideContent"]/div[5]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/span   I got from inspect elements in Chrome