# Scraping data in as it is format for French Characters VBA

Tags: vba

I am trying to scrape data from htm file in the format as it is including hex code for french characters, But after scraping it converts into character which I dont want. Any idea?? 
I have searched everywhere for this but failed to get answer so I registered here with my own trouble.

> src = UserForm1.WebBrowser1.document.body.innerHTML

above code to get the source code

the specific "source text" which I want is below:
the bold font one coverts to Character in extracteed source file.

> `"Intel Inside<sup>**&reg;**</sup><br>pour une<br>productivit**&#xE9;**<br>exceptionnelle."`

but instead I am getting:

```
"Intel Inside<sup>®</sup><br>pour une<br>productivité<br>exceptionnelle.
```

How do I get the text I mentioned first. I have just started my VBA so I might sound naive, so please be lil gentle with me.

Thanks:)

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: its in file://****/Test/sachin_HTML/Test%20File/204217_ca_cs_sb_fy17q4wk6_oa_sb-performance-high_fr_160x600_vr_index.html

Comment: OK I have got another link as an example: http://www.dell.com/fr/p/laptops?dgc=IR&cid=Q3_New_LT_Portfolio&lid=469x208_P_homepage:_r_3_c_2_t_0....In view source look in line number:559 "title="Système d&#39;exploitation"" output looks like: "title="Système d'exploitation""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the raw HTML using MSXML2 as your browser.  `IE.responseText` is the unprocessed HTML.  As soon as you load the raw HTML into the HTMLBody the special characters are converted.

The `IE.responseText` is raw text.  This means you will have to manually parse it.  I would recommend using `RegEx` to do so.

[image]

```
Public Sub ParseMaterial()
    Const FILE_URL = "D:\test.html"
    Dim IE As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set IE = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLBody As MSHTML.HTMLBody

    Set HTMLDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set HTMLBody = HTMLDoc.body

    IE.Open "GET", FILE_URL, False
    IE.send

    While IE.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend

    HTMLBody.innerHTML = IE.responseText

    Debug.Print "HTMLBody.innerHTML"
    Debug.Print HTMLBody.innerHTML
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "Raw HTML:  IE.responseText";
    Debug.Print IE.responseText
End Sub
```

Comment: Okie one followup question...can we fire .getelementbyclassname in .responsetext??

Comment: No ResponseText is just an ordinary string of characters.  There are no elements.  THe answer to [Extract values from HTML TD and Tr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776484/extract-values-from-html-td-and-tr) should give you an idea of what you need to do.